# Image Carousel is Fluctuating & Not Giving Desired Result

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've just created an image carousel See my Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gd2n6paw/12/

or you can see here :

```
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="container" id="img-slider">
  </div>
 </div>
 <button id="prev">
  prev
 </button>
 <button id="next">
  next
 </button>
```

my jQuery

```
 (function(){

var imgSlider = $('#img-slider');
var counter = 0;
var imgSliderContainer = ['http://www.xenergie.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature.jpg','http://www.pycomall.com/images/P1/Natural_Background.jpg','http://www.gochecks.net/data/media/91/Mobile_Nature_Wallpapers_35.jpg'];


function ImageSliderHome(){ 

    imgSlider.fadeOut('5000' ,function(){
        imgSlider.css('background-image', "url('" + imgSliderContainer[counter] + "')");
    }).fadeIn('5000');

    if(counter >= imgSliderContainer.length){
        counter = 0;
    }
}

$('#next').click(function(){
    counter++;
    ImageSliderHome();        
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    if(counter == 0)
        counter = imgSliderContainer.length;
    else
        counter--;
    ImageSliderHome();
});

setInterval(ImageSliderHome,3000);

})();
```

When i use the 'next()' and 'prev()' function button

```
 $('#next').click(function(){
    counter++;
    ImageSliderHome();        
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    if(counter == 0)
        counter = imgSliderContainer.length;
    else
        counter--;
    ImageSliderHome();
});
```

the image carousel is fluctuating. the images repeats some times and some times its automatically triggered.Please if somebody knows that where i'm wrong in this code thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not increasing the counter

Something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){counter++;
                   ImageSliderHome();
                   },'3000');
```